# How can I properly implement a function at the end of a counter in Netlogo?

Tags: counter, netlogo

I am writing an assembly line model, and I would like to implement a counter to hold a turtle at a specific patch (in this case, patch 3 0) for 10 ticks. Once 10 ticks have passed, I would like the turtle to keep on moving at the rate of one patch per tick and for the next turtle in line to begin its own 10 tick timer once it arrives at the specified patch.
So far, I can stop the turtles at the specified patch and run a 10 tick counter; however, I cannot seem to get the turtles to keep moving continuously after the timer is completed.

Here are the relevant parts of my code so far.

```
to go
  move-tubs
  move-drums
  machine-marriage
  move-machines
  stay
  keep-going
  tick
end



to move-machines
  ask wmachines [
    if not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1 and xcor < 3
    [ forward 1]
    ]

end

to stay
  ask wmachines-on patch 3 0[
    ifelse counter = 0 [
    set counter 10
    ]
    [set counter counter - 1
      set label counter 
      if counter = 0 
      [forward 1]
    ]
    ]

end



to keep-going
  ask wmachines-on patch 4 0[
    if not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1 and xcor < 12
    [ forward 1]
  ]
  end
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a reproducible example (also see the websites' guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))? This does not mean that you should put here all of your code: only the smallest amount of code that is necessary to reproduce the type of unwanted behaviour you are observing. Those who read your question should be able to reproduce it by just copying and pasting what you provide. Also... can you clarify your problem? Is your problem that turtles cannot get past `patch 3 0`? Or is it that they don't go beyond `patch 5 0`?

Comment: If the problem is the latter, then it simply is because in `keep-going` you are only asking turtles who are on `patch 4 0`... you are not addressing any other turtle (e.g. turtles that are on `patch 5 0`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is that turtles leave `patch 3 0` but then they do not move forward continuously beyond `patch 4 0`, it is simply because your `keep-going` procedure is only addressing turtles that are exactly on `patch 4 0` (and for this reason the `xcor < 12` part is completely unused).

In general, it looks very complicated and unnecessary that you are using three different procedures (i.e. one before `patch 3 0`, one for `patch 3 0`, and one for `patch 4 0` but which should really be beyond `patch 3 0`) each of which is hard-coding some location in your model.

The whole point of having a counter is that you can generalise a waiting condition across the whole model, so your `go` procedure can be simplified a lot by simply asking agents that have concluded their countdown to do one thing, and those who have not concluded their countdown to do another thing.

Look at this minimal reproducible example where I have an unpredictable arrangement of stopping-patches but implement the waiting condition in a very general and simple way:

```
turtles-own [
  counter
]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  
  resize-world 0 30 0 4
  set-patch-size 25
  
  ask patches with [pxcor = min-pxcor] [
    sprout 1 [
      set heading 90
      set color lime
    ]
  ]
  
  ask n-of 15 patches with [pxcor > min-pxcor] [
    set pcolor brown
  ]
end


to go
  ask turtles [
    ifelse (counter = 0)
    ;; If the counter equals 0:
      [forward 1
       if (pcolor != black) [
         set counter 10
       ]
      ]
    ;; If the counter does not equal 0:
      [set counter counter - 1]
    
    
    ifelse (pcolor = black)
    ;; If the turtle is on a black patch:
      [set label ""]
    ;; If the turtle is not on a black patch:
      [set label counter]
  ]
  
  tick
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. My problem was that I could not get my turtles past patch 5 0, I reworked my keep-going function to only address certain turtles in the model instead of a specific patch. Once I fixed that, my code worked as intended.